# How do I determine why the cursor moved in a QML TextField?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML TextField that I am using with the Qt virtual keyboard to populate text. Occasionally when I am typing fast on the keyboard the cursor will jump unexpectedly to the end of the TextField. Has anyone seen any issues like this? I have ruled out unexpected focus changes as the cause by monitoring OnFocusedChanged while typing. Is there anything else that I might be able to monitor to determine why the cursor is moving to the end?

I am using QT version 5.15 and Virtual Keyboard Version 2.1.

EDIT: Adding code per request

```
 TextField {
      id: lotTextField

      anchors.left: lotLine.left
      anchors.top: lotImg.top
      width: commonTextFieldWidth
      height: lotImg.height

      background: Item {}

      text: startingLotCodeText
      font.pixelSize: Style._SETTINGS_TEXT_SIZE_3_FONT_PIXEL_SIZE

      onPressed: {
         lotTextField.forceActiveFocus();
         state_proxy.processEvent(EventsQML.EVENT_SHOW_KEYBOARD_REQUEST);
      }

      onTextEdited: {
         state_proxy.checkLotCode(lotTextField.text, false);
      }

      onEditingFinished: {
         state_proxy.checkLotCode(lotTextField.text, true);
         scannerTextField.forceActiveFocus();
      }

   }
```

Comment: Please add some code to your question that recreates the issue.

Comment: I would add debugging to your signal handlers here. They likely are firing in a different way than you expect when this happens - if the text edit loses focus and gains it back quickly that would be a reason it would jump to the end.

Comment: I checked for unexpected focus changes using the OnFocusedChanged signal. The issue is not caused by focus changes. I used the OnCursorPositionChanged to confirm that my issues are caused by cursor jumping, but as far as I know that can't tell me why the cursor position is changing to the end. Is there a signal I could use to figure out the reason for the jump?

Comment: Instead of onFocusChanged, I think you should be monitoring onActiveFocusChanged. activeFocus is the one that indicates whether or not the current Item has focus. Plain focus just indicates a desire for the component to have focus when its enclosing FocusScope has focus. More info here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-input-focus.html